# Why are tables returning null columns in Hive?

Tags: sql, database, hadoop, hive

I am currently using hive to assemble data by joining it with other tables within our cluster. When I use the select * from table limit 5; , all my data is accounted for in all my columns however when I run the same check an hour later, all my columns come back as null. What are some reasons why this is happening? Please note that I did not modify or drop anything. All I did was re-check the table I made.

Comment: what do you mean by re-check. You should specify your table DDL and a sample data from file to understand the issue better.

Comment: Did this happen once or multiple times?

Comment: Maybe you didn't commit your data and the transaction is timing out and getting rolled back?